# UK refusal on my family visa

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I applied for my family to visit the UK and they were refused because she stated in the form she is going for 10 days and she didnt provide her account so no prove of her daily circumstances and also no prove of how i support her and also they saw large flows of money in both account i gave and no source of the income despite providing my company's details. What should i do?

Comment: Please have a read of the linked answer and ask another question if there is something specific you need to know.

Comment: @Abiodun Olukoya Don’t waste your money re-applying unless you can address all of the refusal reasons and provide solid evidence to prove it.

Comment: Yes i have already re-applied.. I printed my wife account for them, printed all receipts of all purchases which leads to the money in my account.

Comment: @Abiodun Olukoya In addition to bank statements, providing financial statements (trading and profit & loss account and a balance sheet) for your company along with your latest tax return would have been a good idea.